# Connect my bot in framework composer with a azure function

Tags: botframework

I made a bot in bot framework composer and i made one azure function.

I want to call this function in a dialog of my bot.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your Azure Function, once configured and published, should be accessible through HTTP requests. You can make use of the [Send an HTTP Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-send-http-request?tabs=v2x) action in Composer to send a request to your Function. The linked documentation page shows you how to do this and how to retrieve the response.